# Can the Google API request details about itself?

Tags: google-api

Facebook Applications can request details about themselves, which is helpful as we only need to grab the id and secret for an application and can load the rest from Facebook. Is it possible to do the same with googles API acces?

Comment: Facebook SDK is not equal to Google API. They work differently.

Comment: @ShivanRaptor I am very aware of that. :) That's why I'm asking if there's something similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't seem possible to introspect with the Google API.